# Difference between async callback notation?

Tags: javascript, callback, async-await

What is the difference between:

```
cors(async (req, res) => {
  // ...
})
```

and:

```
cors(req, res, async => {
  // ...
})
```

The result is the same. I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be great to know the signature of your function `cors`. With a standard implementation the results can't be same.

The first `cors` call does the following:
it calls `cors` with just one parameter. This first and only parameter is a function with two parameters `req` and `res` and a promise result.

The second `cors` call does this:
it calls `cors` with three parameters. The first two parameters are not very interesting `req` and `res`. The last parameter is a synchronous function with one parameter called `async`

Could you provide a better example with input and output?